# Match integers among themselves

Tags: logic

I have a query. I have two ranges of integers for e.g., 100-500 and 600-800. This is how they look:

**Range 1**

```
start_range = 100
end_range = 500
```

**Range 2**

```
start_range_new = 600
end_range_new = 800
```

I want a  method logic in which I can match the two ranges (range 1 and range 2) so that these two ranges are completely exclusive, meaning that these two ranges don't intersect.

If the two ranges intersect, then make a local variable as `true` and if they don't, the local variable should be `false`.

Comment: Why is this tagged [c] ?

Comment: what have u tried till now, post your logic here

Comment: @Michael - that was by mistake

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use Rails (or ActiveSupport), you can use [`Range#overlaps?`](http://devdocs.io/rails/range#method-i-overlaps-3F) method:

```
# Compare two ranges and see if they overlap each other

# (1..5).overlaps?(4..6) # => true
# (1..5).overlaps?(7..9) # => false
```

If you don't want to use ActiveSupport, you can implement it yourself as a helper function:

```
# Compare two ranges and see if they overlap each other
# overlaps?(1..5, 4..6) # => true
# overlaps?(1..5, 7..9) # => false
def overlaps?(one, another)
  one.cover?(other.first) || other.cover?(one.first)
end
```

Answer (score 4):

```
variable = !((start_range_new > end_range) || (start_range > end_range_new))
```

Comment: start_range = 100, end_range = 500 , start_range_new = 400, end_range_new = 800, here 400 lies in range 1 , but your answer gives variable as false

Comment: you're right, it should return opposite value :) Edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = (0..20)
b = (15..30)

def exclusive?(x,y)
    return x.first > y.last || x.last < y.first
end

exclusive?(a,b) //False
```